# Is it possible to use Google Places Autocomplete Service in a managed Expo app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, google-places-api

I've been scouring the web and I've found several posts that almost seem to address my issue, but none that I've found seem to get it quite right. I'm developing an app in Expo using the managed workflow, and all I want is a simple input component that will suggest/autocomplete names of cities/towns as the user types. The Google Places API has their Place Autocomplete, and the AutocompleteServices class seems to be a way to handle this without a prebuild UI component (as their components expect basic HTML elements).

The trouble is: The only way to import this library seems to be with a `<script>` tag, and it's my understanding (please current my if I'm wrong because I am comploetely new to mobile development), that you can't simply put an HTML script tag on a "page" in React Native/Expo.

I've been looking into solutions via NPM packages, but the best solution I've found - "react-native-google-places-autocomplete" - uses the Autocomplete query request instead of the basic request. The problem here is that the query form of the request doesn't allow you to filter by place type. (I need to list only cities/towns, which can only be done with the bbasic Autocomplete request, as far as I can tell).

So, basically, all I want is access to the library so I can build what I need myself, but every instruction I've found for importing it assumes you can use a `<script>` tag in an HTML document.

I thought what I wanted to do was simple, but apparently not? Is there something I'm overlooking (i.e. no one has mentioned it because it's so simple)? Should I just go use GeoDB instead? (I'd really like to use Google Maps if possible, as the app will need more complex location-based functionality later down the road).

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: city and town internationally?

Comment: Your question need to be edited to show exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: here is a library that you can use: https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete - if it doesn't do exactly what you want, you can refer to the source to see how they interact with the google places api and build your own tool

Comment: Thanks, Brent, for the suggestion. Digging into the source alerted me to a fact I had completely missed because I was only looking at the client-side usage of the library. For anyone else looking for answers, you'll need to use the Places API in its "server" form, using HTTP requests, not one of the widgets or libraries. It actually looks like React Native Google Places Autocomplete might be the right fit after all; the naming and variety of different documentation just confused me horribly.